# How to negate filename after a specific term in a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that detect urls:

```
 @"((http|ftp|https)\:\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?";
```

I am using it with regex.replace to remove urls from text.

I do not want it to replace any word that starts with /images

for example if the text is "this is my text here is a link http://dfdf.com and my is /images/dd.gif"
I need the http://dfdf.com replaces but not the /images/dd.gif

my regex replaces the dd.gif
so I want to negate any word after images/

any idea how can I fix this ?

Comment: What should happen to `http://dfdf.com/images/dd.gif` ?

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)(?:(?:https?|ftps?)://)?([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?`. Note `\w` matches `_`, so `[\w_]` = `\w`.

Comment: Or, `\b(?<!\bimages/)(?:(?:https?|ftps?)://)?([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?`? See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3c!%5cbimages%2f%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3ahttps%3f%7cftps%3f%29%3a%2f%2f%29%3f%28%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%29%2b%29%28%5b%5cw.%2c%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%3a%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d*%5b%5cw%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d%29%3f&i=this+is+my+text+here+is+a+link+http%3a%2f%2fdfdf.com+and+my+is+%2fimages%2fdd.gif).

Comment: See the [first pattern demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3ahttps%3f%7cftps%3f%29%3a%2f%2f%29%3f%28%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%29%2b%29%28%5b%5cw.%2c%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%3a%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d*%5b%5cw%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d%29%3f&i=this+is+my+text+here+is+a+link+http%3a%2f%2fdfdf.com+and+my+is+%2fimages%2fdd.gif)

Comment: You don't need to escape `:` and `/`, unless you want to make your regex more unreadable.

Comment: @BuhBuh - it's a risk I can take :-) obviously it will not be replaced...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start matching after a word boundary, and fail the match if it is immediately preceded with a whole "word" `images/` using

```cs
\b(?<!\bimages/)(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)?([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3c!%5cbimages%2f%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3ahttp%7cftp%29s%3f%3a%2f%2f%29%3f%28%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%29%2b%29%28%5b%5cw.%2c%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%3a%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d*%5b%5cw%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d%29%3f&i=this+is+my+text+here+is+a+link+http%3a%2f%2fdfdf.com+and+my+is+%2fimages%2fdd.gif). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\bimages/)` - no `images/` as a whole word is allowed immediately on the left
- `(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)?` - an optional sequence of either `http` or `ftp` followed with an optional `s` and then `://` substring
- `([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)` - Group 1: one or more word or hyphen chars followed with one or more sequences of a `.` and then one or more word or hyphen chars
- `([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?` - an optional Group 2: zero or more word chars or chars from the `.,@?^=%&:/~+#-` set and then a word char or a char from the `@?^=%&/~+#-` set.

Comment: thanks, I've used your solution and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you could match match what you don't want to remove and capture what you do want to remove.

You can use a callback with [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0) and test for the existence of group 1. If it is there, return an empty string. If it is not there, return the match to leave it unchanged.

```
\S*/images\S*|(?<!\S)((?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?[\w-]+(?:(?:\.[\w-]+)+)(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?)
```

**Explanation**

- `\S*/images\S*` Match `/images` preceded and followed by optional non whitespace chars that your want to keep
- `|` Or
- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `((?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?[\w-]+(?:(?:\.[\w-]+)+)(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?)` The pattern that you tried with some minor changes to make it a bit shorter

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cS*%2fimages%5cS*%7c%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3ahttps%3f%7cftp%29%3a%2f%2f%29%3f%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%29%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5b%5cw.%2c%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%3a%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d*%5b%5cw%40%3f%5e%3d%25%26%2f%7e%2b%23-%5d%29%3f%29&i=this+is+my+text+here+is+a+link+http%3a%2f%2fdfdf.com+and+my+is+%2fimages%2fdd.gif%0d%0a%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fwww.test.com%2fimages%2fdd.gif) *(Click on the Table tab to see the matches)*

For example

```
var s = @"this is my text here is a link http://dfdf.com and my is /images/dd.gif";
var regex = new Regex(@"\S*/images\S*|(?<!\S)((?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?[\w-]+(?:(?:\.[\w-]+)+)(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?)");
var result = regex.Replace(s, match => match.Groups[1].Success ? "" : match.Value);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Z9yK8U)